# How to turn content between two lines into single line?

Tags: bash

I have text file that matches this pattern:

```
### EVENT ###
param1=value1;
param2=value2;
### END EVENT ###
### EVENT ###
param3=value3;
param4=value4;
...
### END EVENT ####
```

and my question is how do I go through whole file and anytime there are multiple lines between the EVENT and END EVENT lines turn them into single line? Some of the lines in the file are already in one line format but can't figure out the way how to parse it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl solution:

```
perl -pe '/^### (?:END )?EVENT ###$/ or chomp;/### END EVENT ###/ and s/^/\n/'
```